# Postgres Data Dump problem

Tags: postgresql, import, pg-dump

I am trying to dump this data into Postgres:

```
COPY address_types (game_id, device_type) FROM stdin;
1   Ps3
2   Xbox
3   Other
\.
```

But I always get this error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 2: 1 Ps3
        ^
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple spaces as the delimiter. How did you create this statement? Is that taken directly from a SQL script created by `pg_dump`? If yes, maybe the tab character got lost somehow in the copy & paste process.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PostgreSQL documentation on the COPY command the values must be  separated by the delimiter character which is by default a tab (\t). If spaces are used instead I get a similar error on PostgreSQL 9.5. BTW: Which version do you use?

Alternatively you might try to alter the delimiter character:

```
nd1=> COPY address_types (game_id, device_type) FROM stdin with delimiter '#';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1#Ps3
>> 2#Xbox
>> 3#Other
>> \.
COPY 3
```

Comment: I am using postgres 9.2, I still get the same error, using your example [Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 2:  1#Ps3

Comment: @MultiTask: are you using `psql` or some other SQL client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  i am using navicat for postgres

Comment: @MultiTask: I guess Navicat doesn't supprt `copy ... from stdin`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried it ffrom pg_admin same error result too

Comment: @MultiTask: I think `copy from stdin` is only supported in `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry i mean to say that i tried it from psql, the terminal mode and i still got the same errors

Comment: @MultiTask Please provide some more details about your environment: OS of client and server, terminal application where psql is executed, etc.

Comment: @zoliton windows 8, psql is executed from inside pgadmin iii console

Comment: @MultiTask So it seems to be an issue with pgadmin. Using the SQL console of pgadmin on my Linux server indeed results in the same error you have quoted in the beginning. Usually I do not use pgadmin (nor Windows 8) but in my installation there is a menu entry "Plugins" -> "PSQL Console" where the COPY command indeed works.